# Azure Virtual Machines and Endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've created Virtual Machines and assigned them the Endpoints.

Question:
Lets assume I have one endpoint:
1 For port 4444 with two acls:
1.1 order=1, action=Permit, ip=3.3.3.3/32
1.2 order=2, action=Deny, ip=0.0.0.0/0

Does it mean that it's possible to connect to this instance only from ip 3.3.3.3 and only to port 4444? All other connections from another IPs or to another ports will be rejected? Including the SSH ones..

Comment: This is a ServerFault question, not a StackOverflow question. Please ask it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should be moved to ServerFault, but...

You opened a single endpoint on port 4444. Therefore, only traffic targeted at port 4444 will get through.

You set up a mask with an exact ip address (3.3.3.3/32). That is the only IP address that will be allowed through, on port 4444.

If you set up your VM in Azure, you get an ssh port created for you. You can assign ACLs to that port as well, but each port will have its own ACLs. So your ACL on port 4444 doesn't impact the ssh port.

Comment: Ok, so if I do not have an Endpoint for SSH, nobody will be able to connect to my instance using SSH, right?

Comment: if you don't have an ssh endpoint, you will be locked out of your vm unless you have it in a virtual network accessible by another vm. Please ask any additional questions as *questions* not comments, and if they're about infrastructure, ask on ServerFault.